# taylor series expansion for a rational function

Tags: calculus, special-functions, taylor-expansion

What is the Taylor Series Expansion (function of z ) for

[image]

where $\eta$, $n$ and $p$ are positive real constants

Based on the answers in the comments, does this mean that the taylor series is given as

[image]

Are there any conditions on the value of ($\eta z$)?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

Use the binomial series of $(1+\alpha)^{-p}$. The replace each $\alpha$ by $(\eta z)^n$.

The binomial series will start:

$$\frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^p} = 1 -p\alpha + \frac{p(p+1)}{2!}\alpha^2 - \frac{p(p+1)(p+2)}{3!}\alpha^3+\cdots $$

Comment: So how can I use this fact to get the Taylor series of my problem?

Comment: and can this be written in terms of the gamma function? I mean the coefficients of \alpha?

Comment: @user84310 I believe so. Have a look on Wikipedia. There are articles on the *Binomial Series* and the *Binomial Coefficients*. In the latter article there is a section on the generalized binomial coefficients:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series

Comment: See my EDIT please